# /users/{id}/associated - inconsistent behavior

Tags: bug, status-norepro

`/users/{id}/associated` occasionally returns empty for an association even though there are definitely associated users. Calling it again immediately returns expected results.

```
GET /1.0/users/e58345f5-0f7b-4261-b449-3959c596f91f/associated?key=qgAq_KfDu0KYzlNG-qaTuw HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: SOAPI.CS
Accept-Encoding: gzip,gzip
Host: stackauth.com


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 31 Jul 2010 12:42:37 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 31

{
  "associated_users": []
}

------------------------------------------------------------------
GET /1.0/users/e58345f5-0f7b-4261-b449-3959c596f91f/associated?key=qgAq_KfDu0KYzlNG-qaTuw HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: SOAPI.CS
Accept-Encoding: gzip,gzip
Host: stackauth.com


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 31 Jul 2010 12:43:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 9317

{
  "associated_users": [
    {
      "user_id": 1113,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 101,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Cooking",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/cooking/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.cooking.stackexchange.com",
        "site_url": "http://cooking.stackexchange.com",
        "description": "Q&A for food and cooking",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchy/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "state": "open_beta",
        "styling": {
          "link_color": "#0077CC",
          "tag_foreground_color": "#000",
          "tag_background_color": "#FFF"
        }
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 1113,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 101,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Cooking Meta",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/cookingmeta/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.meta.cooking.stackexchange.com",
        "site_url": "http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com",
        "description": "Q&A about the cooking site",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchymeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "state": "linked_meta",
        "styling": {
          "link_color": "#3D3D3D",
          "tag_foreground_color": "#666666",
          "tag_background_color": "#FFF"
        }
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 1434,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 101,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Gaming",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/gaming/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.gaming.stackexchange.com",
        "site_url": "http://gaming.stackexchange.com",
        "description": "Q&A for passionate videogamers on all platforms",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchy/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "state": "open_beta",
        "styling": {
          "link_color": "#0077CC",
          "tag_foreground_color": "#000",
          "tag_background_color": "#FFF"
        }
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 144906,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 1413,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Meta Stack Overflow",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com",
        "site_url": "http://meta.stackoverflow.com",
        "description": "Q&A about the Stack Exchange engine powering these sites",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "state": "normal",
        "styling": {
          "link_color": "#3D3D3D",
          "tag_foreground_color": "#6F6F6F",
          "tag_background_color": "#E7E7E7"
        }
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 38306,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 111,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Server Fault",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/serverfault/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.serverfault.com",
        "site_url": "http://serverfault.com",
        "description": "Q&A for system administrators and IT professionals",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/serverfault/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "state": "normal",
        "styling": {
          "link_color": "#10456A",
          "tag_foreground_color": "#444444",
          "tag_background_color": "#F3F1D9"
        }
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 14,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 5430,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Stack Apps",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/stackapps/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.stackapps.com",
        "site_url": "http://stackapps.com",
        "description": "Q&A about apps for and development with the Stack Exchange API",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/stackapps/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "state": "normal",
        "styling": {
          "link_color": "#0077DD",
          "tag_foreground_color": "#555555",
          "tag_background_color": "#E7ECEC"
        }
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 242897,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 10592,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Stack Overflow",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.stackoverflow.com",
        "site_url": "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "description": "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "state": "normal",
        "styling": {
          "link_color": "#0077CC",
          "tag_foreground_color": "#3E6D8E",
          "tag_background_color": "#E0EAF1"
        }
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 31747,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 100,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Super User",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/superuser/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.superuser.com",
        "site_url": "http://superuser.com",
        "description": "Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/superuser/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "state": "normal",
        "styling": {
          "link_color": "#1086A4",
          "tag_foreground_color": "#1087A4",
          "tag_background_color": "#FFFFFF"
        }
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 31747,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 100,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Meta Super User",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/superusermeta/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.meta.superuser.com",
        "site_url": "http://meta.superuser.com",
        "description": "Q&A about the computer enthusiasts and power users site",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/superusermeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "state": "linked_meta",
        "styling": {
          "link_color": "#0077CC",
          "tag_foreground_color": "#000",
          "tag_background_color": "#FFF"
        }
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 2918,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 101,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Web Apps",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/webapps/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.webapps.stackexchange.com",
        "site_url": "http://webapps.stackexchange.com",
        "description": "Q&A for power users of web applications",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchy/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "state": "open_beta",
        "styling": {
          "link_color": "#163B6D",
          "tag_foreground_color": "#666666",
          "tag_background_color": "#FFF"
        }
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 2918,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 101,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Web Apps Meta",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/webappsmeta/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.meta.webapps.stackexchange.com",
        "site_url": "http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com",
        "description": "Q&A about the Web Apps site",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchymeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "state": "linked_meta",
        "styling": {
          "link_color": "#3D3D3D",
          "tag_foreground_color": "#666666",
          "tag_background_color": "#FFF"
        }
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 854,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 101,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Webmasters",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/gaming/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.webmasters.stackexchange.com",
        "site_url": "http://webmasters.stackexchange.com",
        "description": "Q&A for pro webmasters",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchy/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "state": "open_beta",
        "styling": {
          "link_color": "#0077CC",
          "tag_foreground_color": "#000",
          "tag_background_color": "#FFF"
        }
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    }
  ]
}

------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Any frequency/timing information on this?

Comment: @kevin - nothing definite. just started noticing it as I implement lazy loading on the users associated. I have a few more tests that will be getting run quite a bit so may have more details by tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot reproduce this behavior, probably transient.

Comment: agreed. there was only an hour or so that I was noticing/watching it.